# Adjusted mean for each row in r

Tags: r

Aiming to reduce the impact of outliers in calculating mean of each row, I want to develop a ruled based mean function. 
In the below df for example:

```
2   3   4   5   3   4   5   6   80  3   3
4   5   2   4   5   5   2   4   4   56  3
2   33  4   44  3   4   5   6   80  3   2
1   3   4   1   3   4   5   6   80  3   3
66  66  2   4   5   66  2   4   3   56  3
2   33  4   44  3   4   5   6   80  3   2
22  55  33  33  44  25  34  38  31  34  2
```

So for each row, in a new dataframe (the current one should remain untouched), I want to replace all the numbers that are greater with {current mean(row)} and then get a new mean(row) with the replaced numbers.

The new mean should be inserted in a new column to be compared with the current mean. Any new scientific method to address the same problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use a trimmed mean instead. See `?mean`, and look at the `trim` argument. That would be a much more standard way of making the mean robust to outliers.... standard enough that it's built in to the mean function.

Comment: If you want to proceed with your way, I think you need to work on the logic. *"greater OR less than {3*mean(row)}"* doesn't make much sense... unless you happen to have values that are exactly equal to 3 * mean(row) you are replacing all the numbers. Maybe you mean "greater than 3*mean(row) or less than 1/3 mean(row)? But that doesn't seem great either, especially with skewed data. Better to use a measure of *spread*, like plus / minus 3 standard deviations, or some number of interquartile ranges.

Comment: Please do a small worked example with actual numbers and the desired result. Let's abbreviate `current mean(row)` to be `cmr`. You now say the range is `(cmr - 3 * cmr, cmr + 3 cmr)`, which could be simplified to `(-2 * cmr, 4 * cmr)`. That still seems weird because its asymmetrical. It also won't work well if `cmr` is negative. And has weird behavior if the mean is near 0.  A worked example would go a long way toward understanding.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- , thanks. I am investigating that which method is beat to make is more robust. Is the mean(x, trim=.1) same as calculating with percentile 0.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#Calcuate row-wise mean
rowmean <- rowMeans(df)

#Get the indices which needs to be replaced with mean of the row
mat <- which(sweep(df, 1, rowmean * 3, `>=`), arr.ind = TRUE)

#Replace them with corresponding mean
df[mat] <- rowmean[mat[, 1]]

#calculate new row means
df$new.mean <- rowMeans(df)

df
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8   V9   V10 V11 new.mean
#1  2  3  4  5  3  4  5  6 10.7  3.00   3     4.43
#2  4  5  2  4  5  5  2  4  4.0  8.55   3     4.23
#3  2 33  4 44  3  4  5  6 16.9  3.00   2    11.17
#4  1  3  4  1  3  4  5  6 10.3  3.00   3     3.93
#5 66 66  2  4  5 66  2  4  3.0 56.00   3    25.18
#6  2 33  4 44  3  4  5  6 16.9  3.00   2    11.17
#7 22 55 33 33 44 25 34 38 31.0 34.00   2    31.91
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 66L, 2L, 22L), V2 = c(3L, 
5L, 33L, 3L, 66L, 33L, 55L), V3 = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 33L
), V4 = c(5L, 4L, 44L, 1L, 4L, 44L, 33L), V5 = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 44L), V6 = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 66L, 4L, 25L), V7 = c(5L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 34L), V8 = c(6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 38L), 
V9 = c(80L, 4L, 80L, 80L, 3L, 80L, 31L), V10 = c(3L, 56L, 
3L, 3L, 56L, 3L, 34L), V11 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ronak, what about  `<='  ? so some data might be less than 3*mean(row) as well

Comment: @Sean - perhaps you could do a worked example? Let's say the input is `row = 1, 2, 3, 20`. The mean is `6.5`, so `3 * mean = 19.5`. The way Ronak has coded it, only values `>= 19.5` are replaced, so it becomes `1, 2, 3, 6.5`, and then the updated mean is `mean(c(1, 2, 3, 6.5)) = 3.125`. But you want to replace numbers `<=` to 19.5 too. Since all numbers are either `>= 19.5` or `<= 19.5`, we replace all numbers, so the new input is `c(6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5)`, and the mean is still `6.5`.... This is what you're asking for, but it seems useless.

Comment: What do you mean by `<=` ? Most of the data would be less than `3*mean(row)`. For example, for first row mean is 10.7, 10 out of 11 rows is less than 10.7

Comment: As per my comments on the question, do you want to be thinking about **3 standard deviations from the mean** instead? That would be relatively common.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica--, That would be great. How to do that in r ? So I can compare the difference with my method and them trim = .1 as well)

Comment: @Sean I still don't get it. Can you explain with an example? In the last row mean is 31.9, so you want to replace values which are greater than `3*31.9 = 95.7` and less than `-3 * 31.9 = -95.7` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, I want to see new mean with the replaced values. For example for the first line :
```2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 80 3 3 10.7 32.1 4.4
``` so 10.7 is current mean(), 32.18 is 3*current mean, and 4.4 is new mean() from the below ```2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 10.7 3 3
```. (10.7 is replaced by 80 as 80 is > 32.15.

Comment: @Sean Please check the updated answer, if that is what you need.

Comment: @Ronak, Appreciate it.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- , can you explain mode about 3 standard deviation method? I’m very very  curious to compare that as said it’s common with my method.

Comment: Calculate the mean, call it `m`. Calculate the standard deviation, call it `s`. Keep all observations in the interval `(m - 3 * s, m + 3 * s)`, omit the rest from the mean calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach. I am assuming that by 3*mean you want mean + 2*mean (which is the same as 3*mean) and mean - 2*mean:

```
orig.mean <- rowMeans(df1)
df1.trim <- t(apply(df1[, -12], 1, function(y) ifelse(y > 3*mean(y) | 
            y < mean(y) - 2*mean(y), mean(y), y)))
new.mean <- rowMeans(df1.trim)
df1.new <- data.frame(df1.trim, orig.mean, new.mean)
df1.new
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8   V9   V10 V11 orig.mean new.mean
# 1  2  3  4  5  3  4  5  6 10.7  3.00   3     10.73     4.43
# 2  4  5  2  4  5  5  2  4  4.0  8.55   3      8.55     4.23
# 3  2 33  4 44  3  4  5  6 16.9  3.00   2     16.91    11.17
# 4  1  3  4  1  3  4  5  6 10.3  3.00   3     10.27     3.93
# 5 66 66  2  4  5 66  2  4  3.0 56.00   3     25.18    25.18
# 6  2 33  4 44  3  4  5  6 16.9  3.00   2     16.91    11.17
# 7 22 55 33 33 44 25 34 38 31.0 34.00   2     31.91    31.91
```

Comment: Appreciate it. :)